# Any ideas on how to get fax usage by phone number

Tags: twilio

I can see usage by account or sub-account but have too many to click on each one to see what usage is associated with each one.,

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To fetch the data and work with it yourself, check out the [usage records API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/usage-record).